# How to get data from a webpage that the URL returns when opened?

Tags: android, jsoup

I have a search field in website. When user searches something, it creates get request and new page opens with results in it. I want to fetch these results from the webpage opened as result of url.

For example user searches for "Digital" then url will be:

```
http://library.namal.edu.pk/cgi-bin/koha/opac-search.pl?q=digital
```

I am creating url manually on the basis of what user entered in search field.

I have tried it using `jsoup.connect("myurl").get()`. But it shows nothing. Gives some error.

Code is given below:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://library.namal.edu.pk/cgi-bin/koha/opac-search.pl?q=digital").get();
```

The line above gives error. Libraries and `INTERNET` permission is fine.

or can anyone suggest any other way of doing same operation ?

Comment: What is the error generated?